# AngularJS Pass data to view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller that is as follows:

```
 angular.module('myApp').controller('CoursesCtrl', function($scope, $auth, $location, toastr, Course, $http) {

    $scope.selectedCourse = [];
    $scope.getCourse = function(id){
      Course.getCourse(id)
        .then(function(response) {
          $scope.selectedCourse = {
              course_name     : response.data.data['name'],
              course_code     : response.data.data['code']
          }
          $location.path('/course');
        })
        .catch(function(response) {
          toastr.error(response.data.message, response.status);
        });
    };
  });
```

With view as follows:

```
<div class="ten wide column" ng-controller="CoursesCtrl">
    <h2 class="ui header">
        {{selectedCourse.course_name}}
    </h2>
    <h4 class="ui header">
        Instructor: {{selectedCourse.course_code}}
    </h4>
</div>
```

I am unable to pass the data into the view which has the location path: course:

Looking closely in the code, is there something that has been left out or needs to be considered.

Comment: Do you want to pass the data to 'course' path?

Comment: Please use the search feature before posting...

Comment: @Nitheesh, yes thats whats intended

Answer (score 0):

Because you have written code for `selectedCourse` in `getCourse` function so you have to write `selectedCourse` outside `getCourse` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('CoursesCtrl', function($scope, $auth, $location, toastr, Course, $http) {


$scope.selectedCourse ={}; //here was the mistake

$scope.getCourse = function(id){
  Course.getCourse(id)
    .then(function(response) {

      $scope.selectedCourse = {
          course_name     : response.data.data['name'],
          course_code     : response.data.data['code']
      }

      $location.path('/course');

    })
    .catch(function(response) {
      toastr.error(response.data.message, response.status);
    });
};
});
```

Comment: try for the above answer

Comment: still no data displayed.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `$scope.selectedCourse` is declared as array. declare it as an object for your purpose as `$scope.selectedCourse = {};`

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('CoursesCtrl', function ($scope, $auth, $location, toastr, Course, $http) {

//Loading the value based on the existance in parent controller.
$scope.selectedCourse = ($scope.$parent.selectedCourseData)? $scope.$parent.selectedCourseData: {};

        $scope.getCourse = function (id) {
            Course.getCourse(id)
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.selectedCourse = {
                        course_name: response.data.data['name'],
                        course_code: response.data.data['code']
                    }
                    //Keeping the value in a parent controller
                    $scope.$parent.selectedCourseData = $scope.selectedCourse;
                    $location.path('/course');

                })
                .catch(function (response) {
                    toastr.error(response.data.message, response.status);
                });
        };
    });
```

Comment: is there any other initialization for $scope.selectedCourse in your controller?

Comment: Yes, so the issue is your default definition for $scope.selectedCourse will overwrite the new definition. so better you keep the $scope.selectedCourse in some parent controller and initialize the value checking the existence of that value. I have modified the code for that.